# Bulk decline WSUS updates?

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, wsus

Microsoft disgorged a couple dozen new language packs for Windows Vista yesterday, which are currently sitting in Windows Server Update Services on our SBS 2008 machine marked as Optional. No one in the organization needs them, so I'd like to decline them all to prevent any potential confusion or support requests. Declining each one individually is time-consuming and tedious. Is there a way to select a group of updates in WSUS and decline them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as nearly any app, just shift and/or ctrl-click the ones you want, right click and select "Decline"... You are using the newer version of WSUS, that uses a MMC plugin, not the old browser-based interface, right?

Comment: Ah, I was using the WSUS interface in the SBS console, which doesn't let you do that. I'll do it through the MMC snapin... hope it doesn't confuse SBS in some way.

Comment: Don't have any experience w/ the oddness that is SBS, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to configure WSUS to not take language packs down; will help with avoiding this kind of scenario in the future.  Have a look at the synchronisation options.